# Add a contact to a linked exchange table

Tags: exchange-server, ms-access-2010, linked-tables

I am trying to build an access process to add contacts to an outlook folder.  I have linked the folder and can add, update and delete records.  But not all of the fields are showing up correctly in outlook.  Namely the address field.

I have added a test contact and added an address, went back into access and mimicked the data perfectly, but no address shows up in outlook.

Is there something that needs to be done in order for addresses to show up in outlook?

Here is my data:

```
First   Last    Title   Company Department  Office  Post Office Box Address City    State   Zip/Postal Code Country/Region  Phone
John    Test        superduper              500 west T  Test City   MI  99999   United States of America    1 800 555 5555
Bill    Test        Awesomedawesome             600 East G  Test City   MI  99999   United States of America    1 800 666 6666
```

The first record is outlook added, the lower one is access added.

Here is the view I get in outlook:
[image]

Comment: Have you tried pulling `John Test` from Outlook and comparing the object?  I found when doing SharePoint some of the field names are not what you might think they would be.  They may be described as "Address" but in Exchange it might be "user_address_1" as the key with "Address" as its Name, with a Value of "500 west T".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up going the code route:

```
Dim olCI As Outlook.ContactItem
Set olCI = mf.Items.Add(olContactItem)
    With olCI
        .FullName = Trim(rs!Name)
        .Title = Trim(rs!Salutation)
        .JobTitle = Trim(rs!Title)
        .Email1Address = Trim(rs!Email)
        .CompanyName = Trim(rs!AccountName)
        .BusinessAddressStreet = Trim(rs!MailingStreet)
        .BusinessAddressCity = Trim(rs!MailingCity)
        .BusinessAddressPostalCode = Trim(rs!MailingZipCode)
        .BusinessAddressCountry = Trim(rs!MailingCountry)
        .BusinessFaxNumber = Trim(rs!Fax)
        .BusinessTelephoneNumber = Trim(rs!Phone)
        .OtherTelephoneNumber = Trim(rs!OtherPhone)
        .BusinessHomePage = ""
        .MobileTelephoneNumber = Trim(rs!MobilePhone)
        .Birthday = IIf(IsNull(rs!Birthdate), 0, rs!Birthdate)
        .Department = rs!Department
        .Save
    End With
```